# Get changed select box's selected value using variable to specify the select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, drop-down-menu

I know I can get the selected value like:

`var selectVal = $('#mainIssueType: selected').val();`

But how can I do the same thing passing in a variable as the select box id?

**What I've tried:**

`var selectVal = $('#'+element.id+' :selected').val();`

`var selectVal = $(element+' :selected').val();`

`var selectVal = $([element]+' :selected').val();`

**Full function:**

```
$(function(){

   $('select').on( 'change', function( element ){
       $('#'+this.id).nextAll('select').remove();
        //get current selected option
        var selectVal = $(element+' :selected').val(); 
            //                  ^^ this is the problem
        //create a new select box and add to branchDiv
        var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('#branchDiv');
        //give the new element an id matching 
        //the selected value from the previous element
        sel.attr('id',selectVal);
        //set the select box's options using the values 
        //from the "selectVal" object within the "tree" object
        $(tree[selectVal]).each(function() {
            sel.append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
        }); 
    });

});
```

Comment: did you want to set the select box value?

Comment: no im trying to get the value of the select box that just changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `event` argument to retrieve the value of the `selected` option, you have to pass the `target` property of it to frame a `Jquery object`

Try,

```
var selectVal = $(element.target).find(':selected').val();
```

Or simply,

```
var selectVal = $(this).find(':selected').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not work because `element` in your case refer to `select` element not `option`, you want:

```
var selectVal = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this http://jsfiddle.net/8nhmU/20/

```
<select id="selDemo">
    <option value="1">Hi</option>
    <option value="2">Hifds</option>
    <option value="3">Hifsdf</option>
    <option value="4">Hids</option>
</select>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selDemo').change(function(){
    alert($('#selDemo').val());
    });
});
```